# How can I calcalate the average of each row excluding the first value of each row?

Tags: text-processing

I to calculate the average over each row but without including the first value. Example:

```
1   12 13 14 15 16 17 18   
2   21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29     
... --------
```

I want the output likes like

```
1  15   
2  25   
....
```

Comment: do not cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31875190/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `perl` one:

```
perl -MList::Util=sum -ane 'printf "%s %s\n", shift @F, sum(@F)/(@F?@F:1)' file
1 15
2 25
```

Comment: this print only the regular numbers and desnot consider irregular ones like 1.532 also it stops with empty rows (row contains only the first value) because the division by zero

Comment: @MohsenEl-Tahawy: Fixed it! You should include those information in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `awk`:

```
awk '{ s = 0; for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) s += $i; print $1, (NF > 1) ? s / (NF - 1) : 0; }' file
```

result:

```
1 15
2 25
```

Comment: very nice but I have some rows empty i.e. contain only the first value and the commend is stopped when it find empty row because the division by zero

Comment: @MohsenEl-Tahawy, answer edited.